# how to disable warning as error stuff in VS 2012?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am getting this following error:

Error   33  Warning as Error: The event 'Waf.BookLibrary.Library.Applications.Controllers.RelayCommand.CanExecuteChanged' is never used C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\WpfApplicationFramework-3.0.0.450\WpfApplicationFramework\Samples\BookLibrary\BookLibrary.Library.Applications\Controllers\RelayCommand.cs   33  35  BookLibrary.Library.Applications

However, the same code in other solution, doesn't give this error but just the warning. How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the settings in the Build tab in Project Properties.

Comment: What should I change as?

Comment: @Divine: Change the Warnings as Errors settings to whatever you want them to be.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. But I couldn't see my project output running, application running without errors which I click Ctrl F5...but no output in WPF :(

Comment: Press F5 and look for exceptions in the debugger.